# Explaining how arithmetic question equals ARM assembly instruction

Tags: math, assembly, arm

Having x= 5*x/16, how does this equal:

```
MOV r0, r0, LSR #4
ADD r1, r0, r0, LSL #2
```

Please explain thoroughly

What I understand of right now is the first line is basically `x/16`. And then in the second line I get confused on what exactly is happening. I believe the `r0, LSL #2` makes it `4x/16` but then I dont understand what the `ADD r1, r0` completely does. I suppose it adds an `x` to make it `5x/16` but I am not sure how.

Comment: It does not add an `x`. It adds another `r0` which is `x/16`. `r0 + (r0 << 2) = x/16 + 4x/16 = 5x/16`.

Comment: Also note that it should be evaluated left to right so what you have is 5*(x/16).

Comment: ARM has a feature called the "barrel shifter" which can add a bit-shift to an operand at no additional cost. The bit shift is applied during that instruction only, meaning that in this example `r0` holds the same value after the `add r1, r0, r0, lsl #2` as it did before. This effectively multiplies `r0` by 5 and stores the result in `r1`.

Comment: Yea I initially thought the 'r0, LSL #2' also updated the r0 register making it '4x/16 + 4x/16' but then I later found out it does not update the r0 register allowing the arithmetic to be 'x/16 + 4x/16' making 5x/16. And noted about the left to right, I was just trying to visualize it better. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

elementary algebra.   2^4 = 16.  so shifting right for is an UNSIGNED divide by 16. If I have the number 3000 decimal and want to divide by 100, what do I do?  shift it right two yes?  100 = 10^2 so shifting 3000 >> 2 is 30 which is 3000/100.

5 = 4 + 1 = 2^2 + 1.   x*(5) = x (4+1) = (x*4) + (x*1)

just like x >> 4 is a divide by 16 x<<2 is a times 4.

(x*4) + (x*1)  = (x<<2) + x.

elementary algebra

The times five is easier to see with long multiplication (also from grade school, base two is much easier than base 10).

take the four bits abcd times five 0101.

```
      abcd
*     0101
===========
```

in grade school you would take for example

```
    abcd
  *   jk
  =======
    mmmm  this is k times all of abcd
   nnnn   this is j times all of abcd, because j is in the tens position 10^1
             it is shifted left one
```

With base two you are only multiplying against zero or one.

```
      abcd
*     0101
===========
      abcd
     0000
+   abcd
==========
```

so if you wanted to multiply by 6 decimal then which is 0110 binary so you
x*6 = (x<<2)+(x<<1)

times 10, 1010 binary  10x = (x<<3)+(x<<1) or....((x<<2)+x)<<1) (times 5 times 2).